# How can i get Auth response (ex: Email) from sign-in with Azure using Expo Authenthication (Bare Workflow)

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, expo

i hope you have a great day!

I'm in the middle of learning `Expo Auth using Azure` for sign-in to my app, at the moment, i think i have finished the configuration, and i already got the response

`but the problem is:`

i need to know, what email is user use for sign-in, and the response i got is like:

```
Response:  Object {
  "authentication": null,
  "error": null,
  "errorCode": null,
  "params": Object {
    "code": "0.AVUAOn_br_87QEeWJE1gRRLp8JZUWAsn4SlMrJ3ARoeW5xiIAAA.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P9Mz5y-YHO_5MJpyMzFGEX_1BO13SPiqBWHReXV06bRMS_YZoPG1GKYsput0mytF0FGtKiT2uD34fvkwvs98ZBtn2z5uQlHmKgaxMmkq5RjVAdzcg_glT1AsqgDFergWoi3FRJavMn8LiSizFhm9MlzhyaXChDN_OMyAu98zmtH4LaIjuGWVhxh5MgGz4QhRD9TIgxRi8npVrDBbpx68-AXVambsavXskwwLWerHDwLb2gufAsuP9O-DH1tY7knMQHrfQJqurl85RTSAtQq-FwKKTnC_4P7NRpmnG1htvmebFoGIXzWN9Wj38WsWMqin2rGYTys0yCV7hPy6YIBanRIR_0WUbyAkzR919l-_pf3o6B_iCkShq9YJPivOWh-ukCjWbApr9pD__UEt0QpQtQNra92GJjE_m7tLpzl-DlvW1bT77Gc9tvlhsh3rU8N-m69WFavYDffxq8WnuESm2eDSTJM6d6pAOWlApcvaeg_dwA14h88gF_yiUw7wq3uREVmmJo9A8TK7gBFJ7JvFZcizMzCrnBpdI8Cw34ya7HJGqthPqhR4W3fz2anF-gUxCzjBuvuevxrxUMX7VpGw9MPga9v7YEjI61V70ILemePB1fbWZ82natxh-2qAzj0mhdtO5JLLpr-nOovKnM4qZUhksPNup317z4jsVUALK_6Z13dzjPgN9V69HwNSlWiYP7vyvF7Tl61rt-8XIhxqRUdf_Mn6wIvkuDEsFYucYZNyNu8oJ4We81YEIhguqs08t3fdZxiunO7M_hRrsIMhCbRSDxx2l18a3XTgDreepEDhwJES_xxxxxLvSv3u8djryTMY-TwLpF7cejtheQIZbJe3hXXs3SKLQMkS-JxjbiFjrDias45uWubOpuQ1kaHSutq7wa05wdGSYw0OPGguQux0UNwnRAsrNDDD6f57oko1932s28M11GVsUBDOaePoQF3KFtZ90n-rbdxFRHbVli2fDNxQOJPO8qDdSVb_uPuK0609jmP6TxFmbtTWwsvKerZilbiZPdEti45mSsyj9h_ysxd5Mx-Dhwj-5Tang5KxI0ggbiqV0RF4zPsxAuxxxxxbgubh3rdtLQujVDFNf8HJa1k70cNqPYe0Fe0hpfVxjfKqgWcSEqI8MdFfCJXRXdD8ixzd7LKT-X1vlFdr3FZqn939lY",
    "session_state": "ea378174-d80c-4811-bc1f-adc6b732b863",
    "state": "9xrNttNeAf",
  },
  "type": "success",
  "url": "myapp://login/?code=0.AVUAOn_br_87QEeWJE1gRRLp8JZUWAsn4SlMrJ3ARoeW5xiIAAA.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P9Mz5y-YHO_5MJpyMzFGEX_1BO13SPiqBWHReXV06bRMS_YZoPG1GKYsput0mytF0FGtKiT2uD34fvkwvs98ZBtn2z5uQlHmKgaxMmkq5RjVAdzcg_glT1AsqgDFergWoi3FRJavMn8LiSizFhm9MlzhyaXChDN_OMyAu98zmtH4LaIjuGWVhxh5MgGz4QhRD9TIgxRi8npVrDBbpx68-AXVambsavXskwwLWerHDwLb2gufAsuP9O-DH1tY7knMQHrfQJqurl85RTSAtQq-FwKKTnC_4P7NRpmnG1htvmebFoGIXzWN9Wj38WsWMqin2rGYTys0yCV7hPy6YIBanRIR_0WUbyAkzR919l-_pf3o6B_iCkxxxxxvOWh-ukCjWbApr9pD__UEt0QpQtQNra92GJjE_m7tLpzl-DlvW1bT77Gc9tvlhsh3rU8N-m69WFavYDffxq8WnuESm2eDSTJM6d6pAOWlApcvaeg_dwA14h88gF_yiUw7wq3uREVmmJo9A8TK7gBFJ7JvFZcizMzCrnBpdI8Cw34ya7HJGqthPqhR4W3fz2anF-gUxCzjBuvuevxrxUMX7VpGw9MPga9v7YEjI61V70ILemePB1fbWZ82natxh-2qAzj0mhdtO5JLLpr-nOovKnM4qZUhksPNup317z4jsVUALK_6Z13dzjPgN9V69HwNSlWiYP7vyvF7Tl61rt-8XIhxqRUdf_Mn6wIvkuDEsFYucYZNyNu8oJ4We81YEIhguqs08t3fdZxiunO7M_hRrsIMhCbRSDxx2l18a3XTgDreepEDhwJES_Da20GVhLvSv3u8djryTMY-TwLpF7cejtheQIZbJe3hXXs3SKLQMkS-JxjbiFjrDias45uWubOpuQ1kaHSutq7wa05wdGSYw0OPGguQux0UNwnRAsrNDDD6f57oko1932s28M11GVsUBDOaePoQF3KFtZ90n-rbdxFRHbVli2fDNxQOJPO8qDdSVb_uPuK0609jmP6TxFmbtTWwsvKerZilbiZPdEti45mSsyj9h_ysxd5Mx-Dhwj-5Tang5KxI0ggbiqV0RF4zPsxAucumAOpEJwjxbgubh3rdtLQujVDFNf8HJa1k70cNqPYe0Fe0hpfVxjfKqgWcSEqI8MdxxxxXRXdD8ixzd7LKT-X1vlFdr3FZqn939lY&state=9xrNttNeAf&session_state=ea378174-d80c-4811-bc1f-adc6b732b863",
}
```

and this is my code

```js
const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/v2.0"
  );
  // Request
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      warmAndPrefetchChrome: true,
      clientId: "xxxx",
      scopes: ["Mail.read", "user.Read"],
      additionalParameters: { prompt: "select_account" },
      redirectUri: "myapp://login",
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint:
          "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        tokenEndpoint:
          "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token",
      },
    },
    discovery
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (response) {
      console.log("Response: ", response);
      console.log("Request: ", request);
    }
  }, [response]);
```

=========================== EDIT ===============================

i already try to get AccessTokenRequest and exchangeCodeAsync, looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (response && "params" in response) {
      try {
        const accessToken = new AuthSession.AccessTokenRequest({
          code: response.params.code,
          clientId: "xxxx",
          redirectUri: "myapp://login",
          scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"],
          extraParams: {
            code_verifier: request?.codeVerifier ? request.codeVerifier : "",
          },
        });

        console.log("------- Access ----------------");
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log("-----------------------");
        const responseToken = AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(accessToken, {
          tokenEndpoint:
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseToken, null, 4));
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.log("Err: " + error);
      }
      // console.log(response.params.code);
    }
  }, [response]);
```

Here's the log in `accessToken`

```
// console.log(accessToken)
AccessTokenRequest {
  "clientId": "0b585496-e127-xxxx-xxxx-c0468796e718",
  "clientSecret": undefined,
  "code": "0.AVUAOn_br_87QEeWJE1gRRLp8JZUWAsn4SlMrJ3ARoeW5xiIAAA.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P-4Q4towRJ6ni2ygY4-CP3z0OyckxxSzunXKiX--nkhRKwnNHvbMvHKbgyUCFpeN_AaQi1xMZYZJMonH22e7tiqAU6zLk3PWpNDtyTGuQGB-CRBZkLLk-keOUdrWZRCI9k-8c5QDlCzfS6T1keoaFz9QKkmnX225PPOg-RQnhRxEVomG_9yj25ywnwEbr0pt8kUap0sAE8Tdj3LIzilgY-62cHkZWqjchUvBug_5QfY6i8L8y7PXfsFUaKNxvfCTB4kTFXZc-nC1LtirGsAqZSj1WWQXHejZNB368SNzYClKO65y_t9wZFz7r7gtMDBAaoABp9No1zfuHPUXiS1cEXlWpCsha5vjG8B20xxxxx7vdWNT88CYw5dWvELDPq0QRxJ8uqSrPTLJ9KPA32wwjrTFuWVuW7_oWhrl02tIImRDYsdkWUfM1xgVzahY22hi6gi7wkwmepR6ofoMOiFH29WAoOljHCD22ER3IB_Krt7Kxikkunn0gXx9V0055bqr29nRrl-kQuyMxCqBgYcoWATj8_C5bPiyG07GY1P3Xwi1QtesS8_H0N0rQjCqdM62ks6g6n-WD8Z0HLf7lec8DgbDDf82tJs2JIn9Xjpa2KqJ4Rw3m7KhLJIcYp81gGB5xfYiSnvSKhT6ibSrrbOOe467pOcSIsCC600XqcXea-wfBeBczJLR4es0EEDpjPEwJB4cOa1sDV1bAVzKjTizY7fiGCr-pWyQT4Jig66sqVPaMP2LFqKbSigOICOunihySdVX297uaocbCVWYU2oubkBqQYT-adWeo2I1X4TqkXmGGD0s50og1oNfuJjEvJaxhpaPPR2FO-Hv1Bj-GqUMylAWVG95Fs9HpC4VIv5ceib3NVEgMIivKtLc-JVY4stLcua8hdUn3GsZMjxZBb6dvZuSzI08DwzDl0NrV0PuJzhzEt8S3HhE9xesQlbS2X4G-asyMJUDtTR1286SFFzwalkyt18rwaLbh08nfBJDfxH_3PE5ojhmeGbfa6tvzXr-V1u4EG0uAa-OHsesseVuGfKdUtM6uc3ZxlCF77SU-ZLJhFKP1D3zQ7SIp3JShuobw7PShTt8YVfWlZD2psG67RP1ht-JNwXzCtKe4SoUl_Loi5jZeojcsQt3c1rXdd7BR7k4niRn3x56x6EYP3kgf4abQUi7AmFLkXl369fD3uNGosWxXfv-A3uJyV6zr5sqWtBOy6ONwsA_fSa4cHQ5M",
  "extraParams": Object {
    "code_verifier": "T2VLnxBT7HWyZMAxuiwAWHrcuywNmhGf6GxxxxEJU8iPSnkqAXx6dfaLutGnczQmD4jOjQEp47CG9PlipEaXHJZqJDBAGGOTl5RR6AUlMzB7Yi1bSiGjhq3iOyd8",
  },
  "grantType": "authorization_code",
  "redirectUri": "binusfma://login",
  "request": Object {
    "clientId": "0b585496-e127-4c29-ac9d-c0468796e718",
    "code": "0.AVUAOn_br_87QEeWJE1gRRLp8JZUWAsn4SlMrJ3ARoeW5xiIAAA.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P-4Q4towRJ6ni2ygY4-CP3z0OyckxxSzunXKiX--nkhRKwnNHvbMvHKbgyUCFpeN_AaQi1xMZYZJMonH22e7tiqAU6zLk3PWpNDtyTGuQGB-CRBZkLLk-keOUdrWZRCI9k-8c5QDlCzfS6T1keoaFz9QKkmnX225PPOg-RQnhRxEVomG_9yj25ywnwEbr0pt8kUap0sAE8Tdj3LIzilgY-62cHkZWqjchUvBug_5QfY6i8L8y7PXfxxxxxFXZc-nC1LtirGsAqZSj1WWQXHejZNB368SNzYClKO65y_t9wZFz7r7gtMDBAaoABp9No1zfuHPUXiS1cEXlWpCsha5vjG8B20R69zO8pXkOUVIa7vdWNT88CYw5dWvELDPq0QRxJ8uqSrPTLJ9KPA32wwjrTFuWVuW7_oWhrl02tIImRDYsdkWUfM1xgVzahY22hi6gi7wkwmepR6ofoMOiFH29WAoOljHCD22ER3IB_Krt7Kxikkunn0gXx9V0055bqr29nRrl-kQuyMxCqBgYcoWATj8_C5bPiyG07GY1P3Xwi1QtesS8_H0N0rQjCqdM62ks6g6n-WD8Z0HLf7lec8DgbDDf82tJs2JIn9Xjpa2KqJ4Rw3m7KhLJIcYp81gGB5xfYiSnvSKhT6ibSrrbOOe467pOcSIsCC600XqcXea-wfBeBczJLR4es0EEDpjPEwJB4cOa1sDV1bAVzKjTizY7fiGCr-pWyQT4Jig66sqVPaMP2LFqKbSigOICOunihySdVX297uaocbCVWYU2oubkBqQYT-adWeo2I1X4TqkXmGGD0s50og1oNfuJjEvJaxhpaPPR2FO-Hv1Bj-GqUMylAWVG95Fs9HpC4VIv5ceib3NVEgMIivKtLc-JVY4stLcua8hdUn3GsZMjxZBb6dvZuSzI08DwzDl0NrV0PuJzhzEt8S3HhE9xesQlbS2X4G-asyMJUDtTR1286SFFzwalkyt18rwaLbh08nfBJDfxH_3PE5ojhmeGbfa6tvzXr-V1u4EG0uAa-OHsesseVuGfKdUtM6uc3ZxlCF77SU-ZLJhFKP1D3zQ7SIp3JShuobw7PShTt8YVfWlZD2psG67RP1ht-JNwXzCtKe4SoUl_Loi5jZeojcsQt3c1rXdd7BR7k4niRn3x56x6EYP3kgf4abQUi7AmFLkXl369fD3uNGosWxXfv-A3uJyV6zr5sqWtBOy6ONwsA_fSa4cHQ5M",
    "extraParams": Object {
      "code_verifier": "T2VLnxBT7HWyZMAxuiwAWHrcuywNmhGf6GjjjxxxxEJU8iPSnkqAXx6dfaLutGnczQmD4jOjQEp47CG9PlipEaXHJZqJDBAGGOTl5RR6AUlMzB7Yi1bSiGjhq3iOyd8",
    },
    "redirectUri": "binusfma://login",
    "scopes": Array [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "offline_access",
    ],
  },
  "scopes": Array [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "offline_access",
  ],
}
```

and this is what i get with `responseToken`

```
{
    "_U": 0,
    "_V": 0,
    "_W": null,
    "_X": null
}
```

in the terminal, i got warning like:
`AADSTS501481: The Code_Verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request`

`and i still get no email or username`
can you help me? please :(

Comment: Hi Haksatrya Bhaswara, AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync is a promise, you can do this:
AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(accessToken, {
          tokenEndpoint:
            'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('------- Response Token ----------------');

            console.log('res ', res);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
I was able to query here in postman with the accessToken I got there.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync is a promise, you can do this:

```js
AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(accessToken, {
          tokenEndpoint:
            'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('------- Response Token ----------------');

            console.log('res ', res);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I was able to query here in postman with the accessToken I got there.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me